# Jmeter - Creating Nonce with jboss libs

Tags: jboss, jmeter, nonce

im trying to generate a Nonce string to use in my soap request. Ive found some jboss functions and imported the binaries to the /lib folder.

My code looks like this:

```
import org.jboss.ws.extensions.security.nonce.DefaultNonceGenerator;
import org.jboss.util.Base64;

//Generate Nonce security key
DefaultNonceGenerator nonceGen = new DefaultNonceGenerator();
String Nonce = nonceGen.generateNonce();

vars.put("Nonce", Nonce);
```

However im getting these errors in jmeter.log:

```
2014/02/18 10:02:37 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method:      eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.jboss.ws.extensions.security.nonce.DefaultNonceGenerator; import org. . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation nonceGen.generateNonce 
2014/02/18 10:02:37 WARN  - jmeter.modifiers.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval    Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.jboss.ws.extensions.security.nonce.DefaultNonceGenerator; import org. . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation nonceGen.generateNonce
```

Anyone knows what im doing wrong? Im at a loss :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to check first all required libraries and dependencies are present in Jmeter runtime(lib/ext).
Then restart and try,

If you still getting error, try to make your own jar file using following code,

Instead of **org.jboss.util.Base64** class you can use [this Base64 jar file](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/) , put your jar file and  [Base64 jar](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/) in **bin/ext** folder and restart Jmeter

`import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
      import org.jboss.util.Base64;`

```
  public class MyDefaultNonceGenerator     
  {
     public String generateNonce()
     {
        try
        {
           SecureRandom pseudoRng;
           pseudoRng = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHAPRNG");
           pseudoRng.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
           byte[] bytes = new byte[];
           pseudoRng.nextBytes(bytes);
           return Base.encodeBytes(bytes);
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {return "Null";} 
     }

  }
```

You can access this jar file from **beanshell pre-processor** using following script

`var nonce= new yourpackage.MyDefaultNonceGenerator().generateNonce() 
vars.put("nonce",nonce);`

Comment: Refer [this Link](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/) for more information

Comment: Thanks, it turned out jmeter allready has a built in library called commons-codec-1.8.jar which contained an encoder function for Base64. So i solved it using: 

String Nonce = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(DateSeedString.getBytes("US-ASCII")));

vars.put("Nonce", Nonce);